# Date is not saving in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have added datepicker in _form.html.erb page to pick date at the time of creation. but when i click on create button it is showing field cannot be blank. when i see the params, it is showing "dob"=>"08/17/2012", but it is not passing the validation. I am not sure weather it is a format problem. can anyone help me to solve this problem. thnks

my application.html.erb file contains:-

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.8.0.min" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min" %>
<!--%= javascript_include_tag "application" %-->
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

and _form.html.erb contains:-

```
<div class="span10 date-wid">
  <%= f.text_field :dob, :id => 'datepicker' %>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share the code from your view that contains the datepicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably is your format. The correct format to save time to a database is this

For the date , March 1st, 2012 or 3/1/2012 :

```
20120301
```

So the order goes Year, Month, Day in the structure of 4 digits, 2 digits, 2 digits. Protip, you can add more which would be your hours minutes and seconds as well.

So make sure your datepicker is producing that as well :

```
    $(".date-single-view").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"
    });
```

That will add `-`, but it should still work. You can also do other things like have the datepicker on select drop the data format to a hidden input div, and the input field is just for show.

You can also use the Chronic gem to properly parse various different means of time.

https://github.com/mojombo/chronic

Comment: Just as an added note, a date format which includes 'yyyy' will include year with century twice. 'y' corresponds to the last two digits of the year, whereas 'yy' corresponds to the full year.